# Open video file by clicking on cell

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet that has a list of video filenames in one column.

I'd like for a video player to open when I click on a filename.

Is there a simple way to do this?

There's a hack that lets you call external applications using the `HYPERLINK` command:

```
=HYPERLINK("mplayer", "foo")
```

This opens up mplayer (or whatever you tell it to).  However, if I try to pass a command-line argument to the executable using:

```
=HYPERLINK("mplayer ~/Desktop/foo.mpeg", "foo")
```

then I get the error:  "OpenOffice could not find a web browser on your system".  It's probably attempting to parse the first argument and tripping over a space.

Does anybody know of a way I can achieve what I want?  Perhaps there's a way to do this with macros?

The list of filenames is auto-generated (hundreds) so I don't want to do anything manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using %20 instead of the space, though I don't expect it to work.

Does your player have anything like a play-list provision?  It seems that it would be more direct to compile a play list in whatever format that is, than attempt to force HYPERLINK( ) to work here.

The other possibiity is to see if there is a URL scheme registered on your system that will invoke the player, rather than a command line.  Or just use the file: scheme and see if you can launch the mpeg that way.  You may have to monkey with the file path to get it right.  You may also have to %-escape the '~' if you have any of those.

Comment: the file:// option works, as long as the application is a prefferred application for that type of file.  thanks!